# Is there an example that uses the flexible job shop problem with CPLEX instead of CP?

Tags: cplex, constraint-programming, opl, cp-optimizer

I´m a beginner in CPLEX and I want to ask if there is any example available that modifies the flexible job shop example in a way that it can be solved with CPLEX and not with CP?

Comment: An answer below points to [this link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=8ebacb94-8758-444b-a5c2-b9b137b69370&ps=25). It may be deleted so I am preserving it here.

Answer (score 1):

In CPLEX_Studio129\opl\examples\opl\sched_jobshopflex we have a jobshop example with CPO. And CPO is the right method for jobshopflex.

I often get question on how to write that as a MIP even though CPO is the way to go.

One way is to enumerate time with boolean decision variables.

If you want to adapt the CPO model to MIP you may write the following:

.mod

```
int nbJobs = ...;
int nbMchs = ...;

range Jobs = 0..nbJobs-1;
range Mchs = 0..nbMchs-1;
// Mchs is used both to index machines and operation position in job

tuple Operation {
  int mch; // Machine
  int pt;  // Processing time
};

Operation Ops[j in Jobs][m in Mchs] = ...;

dvar int+ s[j in Jobs][o in Mchs];
dexpr int e[j in Jobs][o in Mchs]=s[j][o]+Ops[j][o].pt;



minimize max(j in Jobs) e[j][nbMchs-1];
subject to {
  forall (m in Mchs,ordered i,j in Jobs, o1 in Mchs,o2 in Mchs:Ops[i][o1].mch == m && Ops[j][o2].mch == m)
    (e[i][o1]<=s[j][o2]) || (e[j][o2]<=s[i][o1]);
  forall (j in Jobs, o in 0..nbMchs-2)
    //endBeforeStart(itvs[j][o], itvs[j][o+1]);
    e[j][o]<=s[j][o+1];
}

execute {
  for (var j = 0; j <= nbJobs-1; j++) {
    for (var o = 0; o <= nbMchs-1; o++) {
      write(s[j][o] + " ");
    }
    writeln("");
  }
}
```

.dat

```
Params = <20, 10>;

Ops = {
  <1,1,0>,
  <2,1,1>,
  <3,1,2>,
  <4,1,3>,
  <5,1,4>,
  <6,1,5>,
  <7,1,6>,
  <8,1,7>,
  <9,1,8>,
  <10,1,9>,
  <11,1,10>,
  <12,1,11>,
  <13,1,12>,
  <14,1,13>,
  <15,2,0>,
  <16,2,1>,
  <17,2,2>,
  <18,2,3>,
  <19,2,4>,
  <20,2,5>,
  <21,2,6>,
  <22,2,7>,
  <23,2,8>,
  <24,2,9>,
  <25,3,0>,
  <26,3,1>,
  <27,3,2>,
  <28,3,3>,
  <29,3,4>,
  <30,3,5>,
  <31,3,6>,
  <32,3,7>,
  <33,3,8>,
  <34,3,9>,
  <35,3,10>,
  <36,4,0>,
  <37,4,1>,
  <38,4,2>,
  <39,4,3>,
  <40,4,4>,
  <41,4,5>,
  <42,4,6>,
  <43,4,7>,
  <44,4,8>,
  <45,4,9>,
  <46,4,10>,
  <47,4,11>,
  <48,4,12>,
  <49,4,13>,
  <50,5,0>
  };

  Modes = {
  <1,3,13>,
  <1,7,12>,
  <2,8,9>,
  <2,9,17>,
  <3,7,16>,
  <3,5,5>,
  <4,1,8>,
  <5,10,18>,
  <5,7,14>,
  <6,4,15>,
  <6,9,20>,
  <7,2,11>,
  <8,8,3>,
  <9,5,5>,
  <9,6,17>,
  <10,3,5>,
  <11,7,10>,
  <12,9,15>,
  <12,6,18>,
  <13,4,7>,
  <13,1,7>,
  <14,8,17>,
  <15,10,10>,
  <16,8,16>,
  <16,4,8>,
  <17,2,3>,
  <18,7,14>,
  <19,8,3>,
  <20,10,17>,
  <20,6,2>,
  <21,2,19>,
  <22,10,5>,
  <23,3,2>,
  <23,7,16>,
  <24,1,16>,
  <25,3,17>,
  <25,7,20>,
  <26,2,15>,
  <27,7,1>,
  <28,7,18>,
  <28,6,18>,
  <29,8,2>,
  <30,3,20>,
  <30,4,17>,
  <31,7,5>,
  <32,3,13>,
  <33,5,13>,
  <34,4,5>,
  <35,5,19>,
  <36,1,18>,
  <36,6,7>,
  <37,5,4>,
  <37,3,16>,
  <38,8,1>,
  <39,3,12>,
  <40,2,18>,
  <41,4,20>,
  <42,7,10>,
  <42,9,15>,
  <43,6,13>,
  <44,4,2>,
  <44,7,6>,
  <45,6,12>,
  <46,8,20>,
  <46,2,10>,
  <47,7,20>,
  <47,1,3>,
  <48,6,7>,
  <49,8,20>,
  <50,2,10>
  };
```

I had to use a smaller .dat because otherwise MIP is too slow. Of course MIP and CPO find the same objective.

And again CPO is the way to go : https://www.slideshare.net/PhilippeLaborie/introduction-to-cp-optimizer-for-scheduling

Comment: Incidentally, if you have a deleted answer that you have improved, you do not need to write another one. Just flag the existing one for a mod, use a custom reason, and ask for it to be undeleted.

Comment: Hi, I got the message "A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted". If I see the answer is undeleted, I ll remove the copy. regards

Comment: Yes, that means you can't undelete it, but a mod still can. It is not too important - just for future reference. It does not look like you lost your +10 rep with the deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that CP Optimizer will usually be much more efficient than CPLEX at solving scheduling problems, the product doesn't include examples of using CPLEX for such problems.

Comment: Yes I know but in my case i have also to formulate this problem as an MIP in addition. So I have to modify the CP model. Do you know any kind of examaple where I can see how I have to adapt the CP model?

Comment: It is probably easier to start from scratch: Formulate the model as a math programming problem on paper and then translate that into OPL. Once you have a math programming model on paper it can usually be translated almost 1:1 into OPL.

Comment: Does anyone have the flexible job shop example as MILP?

Comment: Hi see https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=67c2ccb8-7622-40b4-8cd5-4d55b4e9e899 for MIP for flexible jobshop